# How to make @media working for inline CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I need my html file work on `html email`, so I set inline CSS for my code and I still need it can dynamic changes when device is mobile or desktop.

Here is some code what I try:

```
<html lang="en">
<style>
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .separate {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
</style>
  <body>
    <div 
      class="separate-container" 
      style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"
    >
      <div 
        class="separate" 
        style="width: 96%; height: 1px; background-color: #757575; opacity: 20%;}"
      >
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the `<div class="separate" />` width is 96% for mobile, 50% for desktop.
But in the result my separate is always 96%.

Is it possible dynamic changes when using inline CSS ?

Comment: None of the answers here are for HTML *Email*. Are you trying to create stackable blocks, or just different widths? Both are different techniques unique to email. Flexbox, for example, has very poor support, e.g. https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-align-items/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inline style won't help you switch the styles with conditions**

because you have applied `class` and also specifically applied in `style` tag, instead do this

```
<html lang="en">
<style>
  .separate {
      width: 96%
  }

  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .separate {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
</style>
  <body>
    <div 
      class="separate-container" 
      style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"
    >
      <div 
        class="separate" 
        style="height: 1px; background-color: #757575; opacity: 20%;}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

removed width from inline style and applied in class. Now your css can switch between `media query : 50%` and the `default one : 96 %`.

Comment: Thanks, it's very clearly. Helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[CSS works with specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In your case, inline will always be prevalent over everything.

I can't think of a way to make it work without using two media queries or using `!important` like this:

```html
<style>
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .separate {
      width: 50% !important; // This will override any `style`
    }
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#inline_styles) clearly states:

> Inline styles [...] always overwrite any normal styles in author stylesheets. [...] The only way to override inline styles is by using `!important`.